# Scroll down a web browser by sending a signal

Tags: c#, winforms, api

I am trying to send {PGDN} signal to a web browser. This is how i open the web browser

```
curProcess = Process.Start("chrome.exe", "file:///D:/sample.htm");
```

I am trying to get screen shot of that window. since i failed trying to save an image of full page, wanted to scroll down that page and get snap shot.I thought sending '**page down**' would do.But still haven't an idea how to do.
How can I send keys to `curProcess`?

Comment: do you know how to send signal to a process?

Comment: Actually I did not. but Your comment gave me a clue and now i know. thanks 'sendkey.send' is solved it

Comment: did you solved it right now or not? I am providing an answer for you that will complete about an hour

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code provide a good solution for you!

```
 Process.Start("chrome.exe", "D:/sample.htm");
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (p.ProcessName == "chrome" && p.MainWindowTitle == "sample.htm - Google Chrome")
            {
                KeyHandle.SendKey(p.MainWindowHandle, Keys.PageDown);
            }
        }
```

You require this class as well

```
class KeyHandle
{
    private static Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private static Int32 WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys wParam, int lParam);

    public static void SendKey(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
    {
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0);
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an other answer which uses sendKeys class.

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "D:/sample.htm");
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (p.ProcessName == "chrome" && p.MainWindowTitle == "sample.htm - Google Chrome" &&
                p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                KeyHandle.SetForeGround(p.MainWindowHandle);
                SendKeys.Send("{PGDN}");
            }
        }
```

And the class:

```
class KeyHandle
{
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);

    private static Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private static Int32 WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys wParam, int lParam);

    public static void SendKey(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
    {
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0);
    }
    public static void SetForeGround(IntPtr hWnd)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(hWnd);
    }


}
```