# How to send a key to a process

Tags: c#, api, sendkeys

I have started a process and want to post a message like PageDown key to it.

Here is the code for running the process.

```
Process.Start("chrome.exe", "D:/sample.htm");
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.ProcessName == "chrome" && p.MainWindowTitle == "sample.htm - Google Chrome")
    {
       //how to Send a pagedown key to process p
    }
}
```

I created following class but i don't know why it doesn't work?

```
class KeyHandle
{
    private static Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private static Int32 WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys wParam, int lParam);

    public static void SendKey(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
    {
        PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0);
    }


}
```

and call it this way

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.ProcessName == "chrome" && p.MainWindowTitle == "sample.htm - Google Chrome")
    {
         KeyHandle.SendKey(p.MainWindowHandle, Keys.PageDown);
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders thanks for improving post! Have you got any solution for  this post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rewrite your code using SendKeys API. I test it it works well

```
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    if (p.ProcessName == "chrome" && p.MainWindowTitle == "sample.htm - Google Chrome" &&
        p.MainWindowHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
    {
        SetForegroundWindow(p.MainWindowHandle);
        SendKeys.SendWait("{PGDN}");
    }
}
```

To declare the function SetForegroundWindow, use :

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern bool SetForegroundWindow(IntPtr hWnd);
```

[List of keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: please check this question

Comment: please check this [question][1]

[1]:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20040086/scroll-down-a-web-browser-by-sending-a-signal/20041770#20041770

Answer (score 0):

Process.Start("chrome.exe", "D:/sample.htm");
        foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process p in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
        {
            if (p.ProcessName == "chrome" && p.MainWindowTitle == "sample.htm - Google Chrome")
            {
                KeyHandle.SendKey(p.MainWindowHandle, Keys.PageDown);
            }
        }
You require this class as well

class KeyHandle
{
    private static Int32 WM_KEYDOWN = 0x100;
    private static Int32 WM_KEYUP = 0x101;

```
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern bool PostMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int Msg, System.Windows.Forms.Keys wParam, int lParam);

public static void SendKey(IntPtr hWnd, System.Windows.Forms.Keys key)
{
    PostMessage(hWnd, WM_KEYUP, key, 0);
}
```

}

Comment: This is my answer which i provided for an other question but it does not work in win7 i post it that users test code in different platforms like winxp and vista as well